# How can I export the data from the results table in Image J Pendant Drop plugin?

Tags: imagej

I am using the pendant drop plug in ([http://www.msc.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~daerr/misc/pendent_drop.html](http://www.msc.univ-paris-diderot.fr/%7Edaerr/misc/pendent_drop.html)) to get the surface tension of droplets. It produces a table of results in a window called Results, however, it does not have the usual file, save as etc options. Also, when I try the `getResults` and `nResults` command in macro it doesnt give me any results and says the number of results is .

Do I need to edit the plug in to be able to output the results? My aim is to output the results as a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pendent Drop* is an ImageJ2-style plugin that generates a SciJava `Table`. In an up-to-date Fiji installation, you can save such tables using *File > Export > Table...*.

The macro functions `getResults` and `nResults` do not work on those tables, because they require an ImageJ1 `ResultsTable` window.

See also [this topic](https://forum.image.sc/t/pendent-drop-plugin-how-to-use/290?u=imagejan) on the image.sc forum. In general, questions like this one are much better asked on https://forum.image.sc (see also the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imagej/info) of the `imagej` tag).

Comment: Thank you. I am using Fiji distribution of ImageJ. Do I need to install "ImageJ2"?